# bootstrap datepicker click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker with bootstrap-rtl

the issue I had 2 fields, one for date and one for name, the datepicker not shown until I click first in date input then in name input then when I click back in date input the datapicker shown, and this happened only in first load of page then its work fine until you reload the page again.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">name</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="text-danger Bold">*</span>
    <label for="civilIDExpiredDate" class="control-label">ExpiredDate</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="ExpiredDate" class="form-control datepicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 //datepicker
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate: "dateToday"
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: try adding `$(document).ready({....});` around your datepicker initialization code.

Comment: Could you supply your javascript import order?

Comment: Post complete relevant code. Looks like you haven't imported jquery library? Or better create a demo.

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready({
     //datepicker
         $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
          todayHighlight: true,
          startDate: "dateToday"
        });
    });
</script>
```

you need to initialize your datetimepicker after dom is ready not before that.